# Should I use "Categories " or "Pages" for a WordPress Static Site (A non blog site)?

Tags: categories, pages, cms, static-website

I want to use WordPress for a Company Site which is not a blog; that will have regular pages, such as "About Us", "our Products", "Our Services", etc.

What is the best way to use WordPress for this project ? Should I use "Pages" to define individual pages, or Should I use "Categories" to define pages ?

I'm planing to use some free WordPress Themes to design/customize and deploy the site, what should I be aware of if I'm to use WordPress for a non-blog site ...

Thank you for your advices ...

Fawaz

Comment: Have you read in Codex what a "page" is and what a "category" is? I guess you're mixing things up. Please clarify.

Comment: i have a similar doubt, i hope you can help me with this. I'm creating a website to teach languages and i want to know the difference between a static page and a category page. I thought that to add my lessons i needed to create a page, lets say "French lessons" and the add a grid that would display those french lessons. But i created categories and now i see them appearing as pages too. **For example:** French page: www.website.com/french/ The category that showed up: www.website.com/category/french/ I'm confused, which one should i use?

Comment: @Veronica this isn't a discussion thread on a forum, that's not the format of this site. If you have a new question you should use the ask question button. I converted your answer into a comment to avoid confusion

Answer (score 4):

I would surely use Pages instead of posts/categories in this case. Pages are meant to be "static" and posts are meant to be used for more dynamic content such as a blog.

Pages also gives you an easier way to customize the look of individual pages if needed, with page templates.

Have a look at these pages for some more info...

- [Post vs. Page](http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-vs-page/) (at WordPress.com)
- [Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) - (from the
  WordPress Codex)

Comment: Thanks, this makes things more simpler. I  have gone through the links you have given, and it makes the issue much more clear. Will definitely use "Pages" for the non-blog site.

Answer (score 1):

"Category" is simply a [*taxonomy*](http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) for blog posts; so if you don't intend to use blog posts, then you would have no reason to use categories.

Static pages are intended to be used for static content, so that'w what I would recommend using. (Note: static pages don't use taxonomies, unless you explicitly filter the `page` post-type, to add support for a taxonomy (`category`, `post_tags`, `post_format`, etc.)

Comment: Thanks, for the technical explanation, yes will stick in to "Pages" in this case.